# FullCalendar doesn't split events by resource on Month and Week calendars

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm working on FullCalendar with several different resources that I'm displaying with different colors, which sometimes share events. I'm using the `resourceIds` field on events and on the day and timeline views, this is working great as shown in the picture below.

[image: timeline view]

[image: day view]

On the month and week views, it just puts them in the calendar once with the first resource's color. Is there a way to make it split it into 2 events so it can be shown that both resources are busy on the month and week views?

[image: week view]

[image: month view]

**Update 1**
I did find that you can add the `groupByDateAndResource` or `groupByResource` flags to the config, but I'm still not loving that, as it ends up duplicating the calendar. This is doable with 1 or 2 resources, but if I had 5, this would get ridiculous.
[image]

Comment: " I'm still not loving that, as it ends up duplicating the calendar."...what did you expect it to do instead, exactly? In your last screenshot this is pretty much identical to how you envisaged it in your second screenshot. It splits them into two events, and you can see which resources are busy at that time. Other than there being an extra line between them I don't see much practical difference. BTW there is currently no support at all for resources in the "month" view, that is a dead end unfortunately.

Comment: What I'm looking for is for both resources to show up in one day on the month view. From my research, and from what you're saying, that sounds like a dead end. I'm probably just going to have to build a handler for month view that splits resources' events out into separate events with that resource's event color.

Comment: unfortunately yes. Or you could create a customised "timeline" view which shows a whole month's worth of days, with duration of 1 day for each slot.  https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings . Scheduler (and by extension, resources) works much better with the timeline style view.